# How can Clone::clone_from avoid unnecessary allocations?

Tags: rust

The documentation of [`clone_from`](https://doc.servo.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#method.clone_from) says:

> Performs copy-assignment from source.
>
> `a.clone_from(&b)` is equivalent to `a = b.clone()` in functionality, but can be overridden to reuse the resources of a to avoid unnecessary allocations.

Why does `clone_from` (copy-assignment) avoid unnecessary allocations? What is an example?

I think this is a well known concept in C++, but I don't have a strong C++ background.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's take for example two vectors `a` and `b`. Each vector has to allocate an internal buffer to store the elements.

Here is what happens for each case:

- `a = b.clone()` always executes `b.clone()`, which creates a brand new vector with its own buffer, then `a = brand_new_vector` throws away `a`'s buffer and steals the one from `brand_new_vector`.
- `a.clone_from(&b)`: If `a`'s buffer is too small, it will allocate a big enough buffer, but if `a`'s buffer is already big enough, it will copy each element from `b` directly to `a`'s buffer. In the latter case, `a`'s buffer was recycled and a memory allocation was avoided.

Comment: Does Rust converts `a = b.clone()` to `a.clone_from(&b)` automatically? If not, what prevents it to do so?

Comment: No, because `Clone` isn't a special trait as far as the compiler is concerned, so the compiler doesn't know `a.clone_from(&b)` is semantically equivalent to `a = b.clone()`.

Comment: I would actually say that it's not equivalent. In `a = b.clone()` the elements of `b` are cloned then the elements of `a` are destructed. In `a.clone_from(&b)` the elements of `a` are destructed then the elements of `b` are cloned. If both destruction and cloning have side effects, then a  difference is observable.